# Google map api javascript: nearby Hospitals and nearby police station in two different partial views

Tags: javascript, asp.net-core, google-map-place

I have an issue related to loading the map. I have two partial views on the same page. In the first partial view, I am trying to show nearby hospitals which is working fine, but after that when I tried to show nearby police stations on the map, I am getting no results.

My init method for the map is as follows:

```
 function initMap() {
    var aa = document.getElementById('map');
    var pyrmont = { lat: 31.9730, lng: 115.8479 };
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        center: pyrmont,
        zoom: 17,
    });

    infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;

    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(function (position) {
            var pos = {
                lat: position.coords.latitude,
                lng: position.coords.longitude
            };
            pyrmont = pos;
            map.setCenter(pos);
            map.setZoom(17);
            var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);
            var getNextPage = null;
            var moreButton = document.getElementById('more');
            moreButton.onclick = function () {
                moreButton.disabled = true;
                if (getNextPage) getNextPage();
            };

            service.nearbySearch(
                { location: pyrmont, radius: 1000, type: ['hospital'] },
                function (results, status, pagination) {  // Not getting data in results on second partial view
                    debugger; 
                    if (status !== 'OK') return;

                    createMarkers(results);
                    moreButton.disabled = !pagination.hasNextPage;
                    getNextPage = pagination.hasNextPage && function () {
                        pagination.nextPage();
                    };
                });
        }, function () {
            handleLocationError(true, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
        });
    } else {
        handleLocationError(false, infoWindow, map.getCenter());
    }
}
```

I have the same method in the other partial view and it is showing nearby police stations, but once I load the first partial view I can not see the nearby result in the second partial view, it gives 0 results.

Please help me to solve this. Your help will really mean a lot!!

Thank you in advance!!